# Weird behaviour in javascript transitions

Tags: javascript, css, transition

http://spacedout.co.uk/spaced_out_architects_architecture_portfolio

The slider transitions fine until it gets to slide 20 to 21 and above increments when for no apparent reason it seems to slide through all the slides again. It still ends up on the correct slide however.

Does anyone have any idea why it would be doing this?

It uses the (wordpress) wp-coda-slider plugin, I just can't work out why it does this after 20 slides. I've tried using different transitions and time intervals and it makes no difference. Has anyone had this problem before or know where to look to try to find out why it's doing this?

Much thanks

Dom

Answer (score 0):

It slides all the images, but when the slider runs out of images, the next transition returns you to the first image, but with the same transition time as the ordinary image sliding.

You might want to try something like this: [Infinite Carousel](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/)

Comment: This doesnt make much sense to me, seeing as it starts sliding through all images per transition *before* it has run out of images. Apparently the developer(s) behind the slider plugin haven't accounted for more than 20 slides. Like OP wrote, it still works, you get to the correct image, but the transition goes nuts :)

Comment: Yes that's what I'm worried about, the transitions between slides 20-28 rather than 28-1. So you think that the plugin simply doesn't support more than 20 slides?